# Webpack, React, Babel - Cannot Resolve module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I have installed react-hot-loader and referenced the module in the webpack.config.js. However when i try to run webpack to compile the scripts, i get an error.

Please see below screen shot. Could someone please advise of what the issue could be. FYI, i am using all the latest libraries.

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GCa1.jpg

    /*webpack.config.js
    module.exports = {
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
entry: {
    main: [
        './src/main.js'
    ]
},
output: {
    filename: './public/[name].js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ['react-hot','babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
}

/*UPDATE*/
Code update
I have added an "s" after loader. It is now giving me the below error.

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1nn.jpg
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your second picture, you could try the following:

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ['react-hot'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I am now getting a different error after your change. Please see attached screen shot.

Comment: Adjusted my answer. :)

Comment: For those using babel-loader 6.2.0 or greater I needed to take the loader out of the array.   loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'react-hot',
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1):

I've created a starter with webpack, babel and react-hot-loader. Please have a look into my config: https://github.com/skrobek/webpack-react/blob/master/webpack.config.js

and package.json https://github.com/skrobek/webpack-react/blob/master/package.json#L19

Feel free to use it :-)